# storing a complete book in sqlite with translation

Tags: android

I am going to create a Quranic/Bible application in android I am new to the android and I don't  have any idea how to store complete holy book in a database.Is there any UI tool to do this? Or any other suggestion.Kindly help me out.I will be very greatful to you

Comment: How you store data is really based on how you want to access it later.  Do you want to read it from beginning to end?  Search by verse/sura?  By page number?  Search the text?  Etc.  You optimize to have as fast a lookup time as possible based on your usecase.

Comment: first design your database tables and relations among tables for the book. Or instead of storing whole book/s, just store chapters titles and on clicking title, fetch the contents from server.

Comment: Yah I want to read it from beginning to end and search by verse/sura etc.But I dnt want to fetch the content from server.I want it to be an offline application.Do I design my database tables and relations and insert every verse/sura in it?